# Which Oishinbo episodes were omitted from airing on the official Oishinbo YouTube channel?

Tags: anime-production, oishinbo

It seems not all of the episodes from the original TV airing of the anime were released on the official [Oishinbo YouTube channel](https://youtube.com/c/Oishinbo), so the numbers don't match up it other episode lists such as on the disc releases and other Japanese streaming services.

Which episodes were skipped? Was there a reason given?

Answer (score 4):

A total of 15 episodes were skipped for various reasons of political correctness or general fit for general (modern-day vs the contemporary era when it originally aired) and western audiences. The original episode airing numbers are:

15, 20, 23, 25, 26, 27, 28, 36, 40, 42, 51, 54, 55, 95, and 123

Such reason include but are not limited to: depictions male chauvinistic behavior (sometimes female gender roles in society), certain episodes involving Toujin Touyama's much younger spouse, the controversial topic of whale hunting, polarizing episodes on topics like water and car pollution, chemical usage in food production such as tofu and  [kamaboko](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kamaboko) paste, he use of locally sourced vs mass-produced ingredients in certain products, under-aged drinking and delinquency.

The author of the series is known for his polarizing and contraversial viewpoints which has gotten them and their series into trouble before. The most recent one being their [depictions related to Fukushima](https://www.animenewsnetwork.com/news/2014-05-16/oishinbo-manga-goes-on-hiatus-after-fukushima-controversy) post-disaster, which got the series suspended by the publisher for a time, due to local criticism and political pressure.

A notable exception maybe a battle between the Ultimate menu vs the Supreme menu, with one side opting to prove a specific point, involving less than appealing ingredients to a Western audience.